# Problema a la hora de asignar un entry una ruta de guardado de archivo (Python)

Tags: python, tkinter

Tengo un problema a la hora de hacer que el programa cree un archivo con el ID introducido en la ruta introducida. El caso es que la creación del archivo si le preguntamos dónde guardarlo se crea perfecto; el problema es que no sé como linkear la ruta que le introduces para que la guarde ahí directamente, y en el caso de no darle ninguna ruta, con el ELSE hacer que te pregunte dónde guardarlo (que esto si lo hace correctamente).

Soy nuevo en Python y no sé qué es lo que estoy haciendo mal, no sé si es correcto comparar ruta con True, creo que funciona de tal manera que si la variable ruta tiene un valor, será True, por lo tanto debería entrar y realizar la creación del documento, ahora bien, no sé si el problema es esta comparación o es al indicarle la ruta posteriormente, la cuál no reconoce y por tanto, no sabe donde guardarlo.
Si le indico la ruta y el tipo de documento (.txt) si me lo crea correctamente, pero a mi me interesa que guarde el directorio que le estoy indicando en el Entry y lo guarde ahí, en .txt si fuera posible. ¿Quizá debería crear una función que haga todo esto o hay manera de hacerlo más rápido?

```
idchecklist = open("Desktop\IDChecklist.txt","w")
```

Así es como lo tengo actualmente:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog

window = Tk()
window.title("app")

idcheck = StringVar()
ruta = StringVar()

def funcion():
    print("Checklist ID: ", idcheck.get())
    print("Ruta guardado:  ", ruta.get())
    if ruta == True: 
        **idchecklist = open(_ruta_, "w")**
    else:
        idchecklist = filedialog.asksaveasfile(mode='w',defaultextension=".txt")
    if idchecklist is None:
        return
    idchecklist.write(idcheck.get()) 
    idchecklist.close()

#ENTRY ID CHECKLIST
Label(window, text="ID").grid(padx=10 ,pady=10, row=0, column=0)
Entry(window, textvariable=idcheck).grid(padx=5, row=0, column=1, sticky=E+W)
#ENTRY RUTA DEL ARCHIVO A GUARDAR
Label(window, text="Ruta de guardado").grid(padx=10 ,pady=10, row=1, column=0)
Entry(window, textvariable=ruta, width=50).grid(padx=5, row=1, column=1)#, sticky=E+W)
#BOTÓN PARA GENERAR
Button(window, text="Generar", command=funcion).grid(padx=10,pady=10,row=2,column=0,columnspan=2,sticky=E+W)

window.mainloop()
```

Y ya para acabar, habría alguna manera de guardar la ruta del directorio donde guardamos? Es un programa que se moverá por diferentes ordenadores, pero si se usara en uno mismo y siempre quisieramos guardar en la misma ruta que indicamos (pero que puntualmente pueda sufrir cambios), hay manera posible de hacerlo? 
En fin, perdon por el tocho y muchísimas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que de esta manera se ejecuta lo que buscas:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog

window = Tk()
window.title("app")

idcheck = StringVar()
ruta = StringVar()

def funcion():
    print("Checklist ID: ", idcheck.get())
    print("Ruta guardado:  ", ruta.get())
    if ruta.get(): 
        idchecklist = ruta.get()
    else:
        dialog = filedialog.asksaveasfile(mode='w',defaultextension=".txt")
        idchecklist = dialog.name

    file = open(idchecklist, "w")
    file.write(idcheck.get()) 
    file.close()

#ENTRY ID CHECKLIST
Label(window, text="ID").grid(padx=10 ,pady=10, row=0, column=0)
Entry(window, textvariable=idcheck).grid(padx=5, row=0, column=1, sticky=E+W)
#ENTRY RUTA DEL ARCHIVO A GUARDAR
Label(window, text="Ruta de guardado").grid(padx=10 ,pady=10, row=1, column=0)
Entry(window, textvariable=ruta, width=50).grid(padx=5, row=1, column=1)#, sticky=E+W)
#BOTÓN PARA GENERAR
Button(window, text="Generar", command=funcion).grid(padx=10,pady=10,row=2,column=0,columnspan=2,sticky=E+W)

window.mainloop()
```

Por una parte, para comprobar si se introdujo una ruta debes utilizar `if ruta.get():`

Otro error que cometiste fue que `asksaveasfile` no devuelve la *ruta* seleccionada, sino un objeto *dialog* que tiene un atributo *name*. Este atributo *name* es la *ruta* seleccionada.

Finalmente, no puedes ejecutar `idchecklist.write` porque *idchecklist* es una cadena `str`, no un objeto de archivo. Debes abrir el archivo *idchecklist* así: `file = open(idchecklist, "w")` para luego escribir en él: `file.write(idcheck.get())`.

Un saludo.

Comment: Genial muchas gracias, esto funciona muy bien también y me servirá temporalmente para seguir con el programa.

Comment: Pero crees que sería posible hacerlo como yo quiero hacerlo? Es decir, de generarlo automáticamente en la ruta indicada, y que si no le indico ninguna ruta, que entonces me pregunte dónde quiero guardarlo. Esto sería ideal.

Comment: Cambia `if ruta == True:` por `if ruta != "":` o por `if ruta:`. Es cierto que las cadenas vacías se evalúan como `False`, pero no son *igual* a `False`. Si tengo un rato libre ahora lo miro con mas detalle amigo.

Comment: Poniendo if ruta!="" / if ruta:, parece que entra, pero luego me sale el siguiente error: PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'Ruta indicada'.
Y cuando solo indico ID y no entro ninguna ruta, me sale lo siguiente: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ''; cuando a mi lo que me interesa, es que si no le indico nada en el Entry de ruta, salte al else y me pregunte dónde quiero guardarlo... muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: He editado el comentario, echa un vistazo ;)

Comment: Acabo de revisar mi documento haciendo los cambios pertinentes y no me funciona; he copiado y pegado tu código para probar y tampoco me funciona; en ambos casos me da el mismo error de antes sobre el PermissionError: [Errno 13]... Has probado a ejecutarlo en tu PC e intentar hacerlo funcionar? A ti te funciona? Soy el admin del PC y estoy ejecutando el programa como administrador y aún así no funciona, no entiendo qué pasa... muchas gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: Si, lo probé en mi ordenador (Windows 7), y me funcionó. Quizás estés intentando guardar un documento en un directorio en el que no está permitido (Como C:\). No se cual será el problema...cuando pueda revisaré a ver si encuentro algo. Si encuentras la solución compártela por favor.

Comment: Ya encontré la solución, era un fallo mio de procedimiento. Pensaba que podía  solamente indicar la ruta donde se guarda sin escribir el nombre del fichero nuevo, es decir, estaba indicando como ruta 'Desktop', en vez de 'Desktop\documento.txt'; indicando el nombre del archivo ya me lo crea perfectamente. Muchas gracias y perdona las molestias.

Comment: Ninguna molestia. Yo he cometido ese error más de una vez jeje. Perfecto si te diste cuenta